# Unable to set css style for <td> in DataTables bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is irritating. I am simply trying to set some basic inline styles and it is not working.

```
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: Black;">
    </td>
```

The only thing is that I am using `DataTables` API. None of the styles set seems to work there.

Comment: check in inspector, I am guessing there are getting overriden
use style="text-align: center!importanf; background-color: Black!important;"

Comment: even after setting `!important`...it is not working....and in the inspector i couldn't find anything with `styles = text align or background-color`

Comment: ok, I will delete my answer, you need to check and modify the CSS methods which are setting these properties

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<td style="text-align: center !important; background-color: Black !important;">
    </td>
```

Comment: see there is " !important" in style